# Python threading argument missing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am getting a missing argument error and I am following the answer here. 
[Python: TypeError in Threading. function takes x positional argument but y were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116721/python-typeerror-in-threading-function-takes-x-positional-argument-but-y-were)
What am I missing? Help a newbie.
From answer 
"each character is being passed as a separate argument to startSuggestworker.

Instead, you should provide args a tuple:
t = threading.Thread(target=startSuggestworker, args = (start_keyword,))
"

```
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threadManager(), args=(fl,))
TypeError: threadManager() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fl'
```

Here is the signature for threadManager()

```
def threadManager(self, fl):
       #code
```

Edit 
Add more context: 
Some how this code works for me

```
self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.startProcess2, args=(fl,myData))
```

And the definition for startProcess2

```
def startProcess2(self, fnfull, myData):
     #code
```

But this fails for me

```
        if fl != '':
            self.threadx = threading.Thread(target=self.threadManager(), args=(self,fl,))
            self.threadx.start()
```

Comment: Try `self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threadManager, args=(fl,))` :)

Comment: Ahh, time for me to take a break... Thanks

Comment: just needed a fresh set of eyes!