# Python Thread() - Function Arg Tuple Not Working?

Tags: python, multithreading, tuples

I'm attempting to thread a function call in my Python catastr^H^H^H^H^H^Hreation, and I've read up on how to use the `threading.Thread()` call.  My function takes a simple string argument, so *theoretically* it should be as easy as:

`thread = threading.Thread(target = my_func, args = (string_var, ))`
bearing in mind that the `args()` needs to be a tuple.  Got it.  However, it appears as though I'm still doing something wrong because I continually get the barffage from Python:

`TypeError: my_func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I'm a bit stumped here.  Any guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code? Is it a function or a method?

Comment: You'll have to forgive that I can't since it's internal stuff.  It's a method though.  It's simply calling the Python container API to restart a container.  The string being passed in is the name of said container.  Functionally it works fine until I attempt to thread it.  Grr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue is that because it's a method (thanks gribvirus74 for the idea) and I'm attempting to thread it, it *won't* inherit the `self`.  And that appears to be the issue.  I moved the function *outside* of the class and called it with the Thread().  Works fine now.

Comment: No need to move it outside. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

please provide some code for us to help you.
But before you do your post could be a possible duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116721/python-typeerror-in-threading-function-takes-x-positional-argument-but-y-were/37116824).

Comment: I know you read my initial question _carefully_ before answering, correct? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a method, then you can write the following code (assuming the class name is `SomeClass` and it has a method called `foo` with one argument):

```py
x = SomeClass()

thread = threading.Thread(target=SomeClass.foo, args=(x, 'your method argument'))
```

Comment: Right, but I was trying this from within another method in the same class.  That's what was fouling me up.